# I used requirejs oprimizer i.e uglify to minify momentjs but when i use moment it gives me the following error

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

> TypeError: moment is not a function at Object.commonFunctionsFactory.formatDate

However if i minify my momentjs online using [jscompress](https://jscompress.com/) the resulted file working fine for me.

### Grunt Task

```
build_momentjs_file: {
        options: {
          baseUrl: '<%= yeoman.app %>/../bower_components/moment/min',
          mainConfigFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js',
          include: [ 'moment.min.js' ],
          out: '<%= yeoman.app %>/build/moment.min.js',
          optimize: "uglify2",
          preserveLicenseComments: false,
        }
      }
```